# My python interpreter does not recognize strings

Tags: python, syntax-error

Newbie disclaimer: I am new to Python and just started using IDLE to play around with Python.

My problem is the interpreter does not recognize strings, whether enclosed in ¨¨ or ´´.

I configured IDLE to use UTF-8. but it does not seem to be an IDLE issue. What I tried is to test this string in the interpreter directly. It does not work.

> print ¨Money¨

to the interpereter returns

> File "`<stdin>`", line 1
>       print ¨Money¨
>             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone help me with this? I am using a new laptop running fedora15 with the international keyboard layout and **python version is 2.7.1**.

Comment: Well if it was Python 3, I'd say put parentheses around the string, but not sure why 2 isn't handling it.

Comment: Those quote characters don't look right.  Retype them in your interpreter, using the keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `""` or `''`, not `¨¨`, `´´` or any other fancy characters.

Comment: +1 for answering first while I was looking up the actual characters with a hex dump.  The OP was using U+00A8 DIAERESIS and U+00B4 ACUTE ACCENT.

Comment: ok. I got the problem. On this brand new QWERTY laptop keyboard with US international layout that i use,attempting to type the double quote on the keyboard with just Shift key gives me ¨¨, the DIARESIS you have specified. Shift+Alt+double quotes gives me the right character. thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your keyboard setting between normal US English for coding, and US English International for texting, that worked for me.